# Java Hibernate tips about update all table fields performance

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a requirement like this.

```
protected Integer[] updateFullTable(final Class clazz){
    final ProjectionList projectionList=Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"),"id");
    final Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(clazz)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("typeOfOperation",1))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("performUpdate",true));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    final List idsList=criteria.list();
    final Integer[]ids = transformObjectArrayIntoIntegerArray(idList);
    //NOW WE UPDATE THE ROWS IDS. 
    final Query query=session.createQuery("update "+clazz.getName()+" set activeRegister=true and updateTime=:updateTime where id in (:ids)")
    .setParameter("updateTime",new Date())
    .setParameterList("ids",ids);
    query.executeUpdate();          
    return transform;
}
```

As you guys can see I need to update all rows in a table sometime I query all the rows ids and later apply the update to those ids in a separate query but the tables has a lot of records sometimes **takes between 30 seconds to 10 minutes depends of the table**.

I have change this code to only one update like this.

```
final Query query=session.createQuery("update "+clazz.getName()+" set activeRegister=true and updateTime=:updateTime where typeOfOperation=1 and performUpdate=true");
```

And with that only query I avoid the first query but I cannot not longer return the affected Ids. But later the requirement was change a

```
final StringBuilder logRevert;
```

Parameter was added.

Which needs to store the updated ids to apply a direct reverse update into the DB if required.

But with my update i cannot get the Ids not longer. My question is how can I get or return the affected ids using a stored procedure or some workaround in the DB or hibernate I mean get the first behaviour with only one query or a enhanced code..

Any tip.

I have tried

1. Using criteria
2. Using HQL.
3. Using namedQuery
4. Using SqlQuery
5. Not using transformer returning me a raw Object[]

But the times still are somehow high.

I want something like

```
query.executeUpdate();   // RETURNS THE COUNT OF THE AFFECTED ROWS
```

But I need the affected Ids......

Sorry if the question is simple.

**UPDATE**

With @dmitry-senkovich I could do it using rawSQL but not with hibernate a separated question was made here.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641851/java-hibernate-org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-could-not-extract-re
```

Comment: If you want to minimize resource usage and maximize performance, you have to use either a cursor or a stored procedure (which uses cursor) If you do not care about wasting some cycles and your clock is reliable, you can also change your algorithm to do the update first. After update you can get ids by using timestamp, that you set for rows, in where clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following solution?

```
SET @ids = NULL;

UPDATE SOME_TABLE
SET activeRegister = true, updateTime = :updateTime
WHERE typeOfOperation = 1 and performUpdate = true
      AND (SELECT @ids := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @ids));

SELECT @ids;
```

Comment: how can i return those ids using hibernate using a sqlQuery or so?

Comment: @chiperortiz the simplest way I see is to use native query: session.createSQLQuery(this_long_query_above)

Comment: but with that i get the ids? i will check it out.

Comment: @chiperortiz you will get the string of the following format "id1, id2, id3, ...". It is the only thing I've found so far using one call only

Comment: I have try this code session.createSQLQuery(longQuery).uniqueResult() but a exception is throw Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: hey dmitry maybe you can check my brand and new question about the exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641851/java-hibernate-org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-could-not-extract-re

Comment: @@dmitry-senkovich please see my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641851/java-hibernate-org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-could-not-extract-re

Comment: @chiperortiz  ok, I'll take a look

Comment: Syntax problem:  `SET a=1 AND b=2` is _bad_ code.  It needs to be `SET a=1, b=2`

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich - see syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html .  `AND` is a boolean operator, not a separator for a list of things.  (I un-down-voted your answer.)

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed) thx then, it is the first time I'm using the construction

Answer (score 1):

if *updateTime* is datetime 
you can select all affected record ids  with **select**

`Date updateTime  = new Date(); // time from update`

```
select id from clazz.getName() where updateTime=:updateTime and  activeRegister=true and typeOfOperation=1 and performUpdate=true
```

Comment: i need to get the ids and later update those ids. i need to use only 1 sql sentence or make it as fast as possible....

Comment: @chiperortiz - "as fast as possible" -- don't worry about optimizing this until you have demonstrated that it is the slowest part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Updating a large number of rows in a table is a slow operation.  This is due to needing to capture the 'old' value of each row in case of a `ROLLBACK` (due to explicit `ROLLBACK`, failure of the `UPDATE`, failure or subsequent query in same transaction, or power failure before `UPDATE` finishes).

The usual fix is to rethink the *application design* that necessitated the large `UPDATE`.

On there other hand, there is a *possible* fix to the schema.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I don't have to do as much 'hand waving' in the following paragraph...

It *might* be better to move the column(s) that need to be updated into a separate, parallel, table ("vertical partitioning").  This *might* be beneficial if

- The original table has lots of wide columns (`TEXT`, `BLOB`, etc) -- by not having to make bulky copies.
- The original table is being updated simultaneously -- by the updates not blocking each other.
- There are `SELECT` hitting the non-updated columns -- by avoiding certain other blockings.

You can still get the original set of columns -- by `JOINing` the two tables together.