# Java Hibernate org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet on createSQLQuery

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, select

I have this method:

```
private final void updateAllTableFields(final Class clazz){
    final String tableName = ((Table)clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class)).name();
    final String sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SET @ids = NULL; ")
            .append("UPDATE ")
            .append(tableName)
            .append(' ')
            .append("set activeRecord=:activeRecord ")
            .append("where activeRecord=true and updateable=true ")
            .append("and (SELECT @ids \\:= CONCAT_WS(',', id, @ids)); ")
            .append("select @ids;")
            .toString();
    final Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery)
            .setParameter("activeRecord",Boolean.FALSE);
    final Object idsList=query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("idsList = " + idsList);
}
```

I want to do a update and also return the affected Ids this works Perfect using a rawSQL returns the id in a string fashion but I couldn't make it work using Hibernate any tip!

### Update

I need to do a update and return the affected id. I don't want to make a simple UPDATE.

You can [check it out the original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604763/java-hibernate-tips-about-update-all-table-fields-performance).

### Update

The error is

```
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:966)
at company.nuevemil.code.finalizarEntornoDePrueba(Test.java:56)
at company.nuevemil.code.main(Test.java:27)


Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE student set activeRecord=false,uid=1 where activeRecord=true at line 1
```

Comment: Mind posting the error you get with your attempt?

Comment: is done pal thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide the value of the variable `activeRecord` leading into the code you provided.  If it is simply `true`, then the code you provided did _not_ generate the error message you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you won't be able to make it in Hibernate fashion.

Hibernate is independent from a database. But the part of the query that initializes a variable (I mean `set @ids = null;`) is not portable across all the relational databases so I wouldn't expect it to be in Hibernate API somewhere.

Comment: @chiperortiz Yes, but how there could be Hibernate API for a particular database? it's impossible to my mind

Answer (score 3):

```
you have to use HQL Query for bulk update. you are going write way only thing is that, you have to create HQL query for example


    Your Query Might be like this:-
    final String tableName = ((Table)clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class)).name();
        final String sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SET @ids = NULL; ")
                .append("UPDATE ")
                .append(tableName)
                .append(' ')
                .append("set activeRecord=:activeRecord ")
                .append("where activeRecord=true and updateable=true ")
                .append("and (SELECT @ids \\:= CONCAT_WS(',', id, @ids)); ")
                .append("select @ids;")
                .toString();
        final Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery)
                .setParameter("activeRecord",Boolean.FALSE);
        final Object idsList=query.executeUpdate();

    Example Query:
    final String tableName = ((Table)clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class)).name();
       Query qry = session.createQuery("update "+tableName+" p set p.proName=?
    where p.productId=111");
                qry.setParameter(0,"updated..");
                int res = qry.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I need to do a update and return the affected id!! you can check it out the original question here pal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604763/java-hibernate-tips-about-update-all-table-fields-performance

Answer (score 2):

There is no "affected id" in an `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE student
    set activeRecord=false,uid=1
    where activeRecord=true
```

may modify 0 rows, 1 rows, or many rows.

What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `student`?  Let's say it is `studentId`.  To retrieve all (if any) of the `studentId` values, you neecd the Hibernate equivalent of this pseudo-code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
@ids = SELECT studentId
           FROM student
           WHERE activeRecord=true  -- and updateable=true ??
           FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE student
    SET activeRecord=false,
        uid=1
    WHERE activeRecord=true  -- and updateable=true ??
    ;
COMMIT;
```

**More**

That code could be bundled up in a Stored Procedure, thereby allowing it to be `CALLed` as if a single statement.  (I do not know how to make it work with Hibernate.)

Comment: MY SQL works i want to implement it using hibernate but im afraid is not possible....

Comment: your pseudo code works but is exactly how is implemented ready now in 2 queries i would like to do in a single query.

Comment: @chiperortiz - I added a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest extracting records to be updated as list of entity, then you can iterate to set values, persist and still return afected ids at the end of your method